# Facebook ios sdk doesn't work on ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I am using `Facebook ios sdk` for login into my app.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:vc handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    NSString *token = result.token.tokenString;
}];
```

This code works fine on all ios versions except `ios 8.3`. On `ios 8.3` the token is always nil. I use latest `Facebook sdk`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42266558/5461400

Comment: Harshal I test on physical device